# 2D array - invalid initializer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, char, multidimensional-array

Hey guys I'm trying to initialize a 2D char array but am having trouble.

```
int size = 300 * 400;
char * frame[3] = malloc(sizeof(char *)*size*3);
```

Gives m: `error: invalid initializer`.
So I tried:

```
int size = 300 * 400;
char frame[3][size] = malloc(sizeof(char *)*size*3);
```

But then I get `error: variable-sized object may not be initialized`?

Any ideas how I can initialize an array of size 300*400 with 3 rows?

Thanks.

Comment: Not all C/C++ compilers support declaring an array using a variable size.

Comment: Are you trying to allocate an array of 3 character pointers to buffers of 120000 characters ? What is the point of the 300 * 400 - some kind of array in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
int size = 300 * 400;
const int rows_number = 3;
char* frame[ rows_number ]; // crate array with 3 elements, each of them `char*`
for( unsigned ii = 0; ii < rows_number; ++ii )
{
    // allocate `size` char`s for each "row"
    frame[ ii ] = malloc( sizeof(char) * size ); 
    // do not forget to free this memory later
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 - I know, but it's compile time and it's more readable (at least to me)